# How to handle errors in "nested" forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-errors

I have two models:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(_("Building label"), blank=False, max_length=255)  

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('buildings:config', kwargs={'pk': self.id})


class Floor(models.Model):

    label = models.CharField(_("Floor label"), blank=True, max_length=255)

    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, null=False)
```

I have written a custom ModelForm in order to allow the user to change (UpdateView) the building's infos and add a new floor (FloorsConfigForm) in the same page.

The FloorsConfigForm is :

```
class FloorsConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Floor
        fields = ["label", "building",]
```

And the view is:

```
class BuildingConfigUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Building
    fields = ('label','address',)
    template_name = "buildings/building_update.html"
    form_floors = FloorsConfigForm(prefix="floor_")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(BuildingConfigUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ret["form_floors"] = self.form_floors
        b = Building.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
        ret["floors"] = Floor.objects.filter(building=b)
        return ret

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            res = None
            print(request.POST)
            if "action_save" in request.POST:
                res = super(BuildingConfigUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
            elif "action_add_floor" in request.POST:
                # #add the floor , validate, save...
                self.form_floors = FloorsConfigForm(request.POST, prefix="floor_")
                if self.form_floors.is_valid():
                    self.form_floors.save()
                    res = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buildings:config', kwargs={"pk":self.kwargs["pk"]}))
                else:
                    print(self.form_floors.errors)
                    res = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buildings:config', kwargs={"pk":self.kwargs["pk"]}))

            else:
                res = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buildings:config', kwargs={"pk":self.kwargs["pk"]}))
            return res
```

This works very well, and I am happy(!)

BUT the last mile is to properly display the errors of my form_floors form in the template of its "parent".

And this is where I need you!

Note: in the view code above, I simply print the form error (print(self.form_floors.errors), and this is OK since it print

```
"<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['gcBxn72bm6cLFXmpIatplZ0cNtsNgMlU'], 'floor_-building': [''], 'action_add_floor': [''], 'floor_-label': ['']}>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>building<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>"
```

when I dont specify a building to the floor.

The exact question is: how can I render this error message in the main template?

**Edit - Getting closer**
In my post def in view, I changed the Redirects:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                res = None
                print(request.POST)
                if "action_save" in request.POST:
                    res = super(BuildingConfigUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
                elif "action_add_floor" in request.POST:
                    # #add the floor , validate, save...
                    self.form_floors = FloorsConfigForm(request.POST, prefix="floor_")
                    if self.form_floors.is_valid():
                        self.form_floors.save()
                        res = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buildings:config', kwargs={"pk":self.kwargs["pk"]}))
                    else:
                        print(self.form_floors.errors)
                        res = super(BuildingConfigUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

                else:
                    res = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buildings:config', kwargs={"pk":self.kwargs["pk"]}))
                return res
```

It's better, I have access to the errors in the template. But my main form is empty!

It's emplty because in my template, I have two html forms. So, when I send the second form, the POST request don't have the other kwargs.

Now, I need to find a way to "fusion" two requests!

Comment: I'm not so familiar with class based views, but sounds like you shouldn't return `HttpResponseRedirect` everywhere, it should only exist when form data is successfully processed. In other cases, you might need `HttpResponse` instead, so the form is passed to the template "as is", which contains the errors. Redirect will only bring you to the page with initial GET status, thus you lost all the form errors.

Comment: It is the right path. See edits

Comment: Did you in your template wrap both forms in `<form></form>` tag?

Comment: yes. I've tried to wrap both actions in one <form> or put hidden <input> in the second form : it solves the missing data, but I lose the error fields :(